# Set tick interval one minute from axis Hightcharts

Tags: highcharts

I tried with a script to split time one day (hh:mm) into every one minute on X-axis. However, It shows every one hour

```js
xAxis: {
  tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 15,
  min: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 14),
  max: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 15),
  title: {
    text: 'Time'
  },
  type: 'datetime',
  dateTimeLabelFormats: { //force all formats to be hour:minute
    second: '%H:%M',
    minute: '%H:%M',
    hour: '%H:%M',
    day: '%H:%M',
    week: '%H:%M',
    month: '%H:%M',
    year: '%H:%M'
  }
}, `
```

Please help

Comment: Can you please reproduce the problem in online editor?

Comment: Hi @ELIP, one minute interval is too dense for your date time range. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7qk9a58s/1/

Comment: @ppotaczek . Great. You saved me. Thank you so much ;)